# Old releases of OpenSSL loop when generating RSA key

Tags: c, openssl

This is my code:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(){

    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4; 
    RSA *r = RSA_generate_key(512, e, NULL, NULL);
    const BIGNUM *n = r->n;
    BN_print_fp(stdout, n);
    RSA_free(r);

    return  0;
}
```

The problem with it is that it loops forever. Here I include the output when being run under Valgrind - it is this very message being displayed over and over in a loop:

```
==2781== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2781==    at 0x403A51: bn_sqr_comba8 (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x41A63E: bn_sqr_recursive (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x41A92F: BN_sqr (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x4199A5: BN_mod_mul (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x40FE6B: BN_generate_prime (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x4041A2: RSA_generate_key (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/SharedLibraryTest)
==2781==    by 0x4010FF: main (sharedLibraryTest.c:11)
```

Do you think you know what causes it? We are talking about these releases for example (all of them behave the same way concerning this piece of code.)

- OpenSSL_0_9_4
- OpenSSL_0_9_5a
- OpenSSL_0_9_5a-beta1
- OpenSSL_0_9_5a-beta2
- OpenSSL_0_9_5beta1
- OpenSSL_0_9_5beta2
- OpenSSL_0_9_6-beta3

Somebody suggested that it could be not seeding the random number generator in OpenSSL, but these old versions of OpenSSL don't recognize the function `RAND_seed` yet.

Maybe the way I install these versions of OpenSSL can help too:

```
./config no-asm --prefix=$INSTALLDIR --openssldir=$OPENSSLDIR # no-asm because my machine doesn't recognize the old assembler instruction format
sed -i 's/-m486//g' Makefile # gcc no longer recognizes this option
make
make install
```

And since it was requested, this is the way I compile the program:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wl,-rpath,/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/library/lib -g -O1 sharedLibraryTest.c -o SharedLibraryTest -I/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/library/include -L/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/compiling_on_different_openssl_versions/library/lib -lcrypto -ldl -pthread
```

Comment: Wow... I'd like to hear some of the backstory about why you are using OpenSSL 0.9.4 in 2017.

Comment: Research: different libraries (and releases) usually generate different RSA keys as well - all modern libraries are biased when generating random keys. I am to find out how this pattern changes over time.

Comment: Ah, make sense. How did you compile and link your program? Maybe you can side step the issue. I'm not convinced you are linking to the library you expect. These unexplained memory problems are sometimes a sign of mixing/matching different versions of OpenSSL. Also, you are compiling OpenSSL with `-O3`, not `-O1`. You are going to get Valgrind false positives at that optimization level.

Comment: [Here you can see the script I use to download and install the OpenSSL version I want](https://pastebin.com/Pggpt4vT) and [here I link the way I compile the program itself](https://pastebin.com/raw/mkgjf9QZ) However I am not sure how to compile OpenSSL with `-O1` instead of `-O3`.

Comment: So I have changed the `CFLAG` argument in `Makefile` from `-O3` to `-O1` and Valgrind keeps telling me the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried testing if RSA_generate_key return NULL?

Comment: It doesn't return a thing - it loops when it enters the mentioned method.